# Optimum way of traversing a large dataset

Tags: javascript, performance

I have a large dataset of the values as JSON. Following is a small snapshot of that JSON object.

```
 {
     "response": [
     {
         "data": [
         {
             "value": 1,
             "minute": "2019-06-10 11:51",
             "action": "firstApp",
         },
         {
             "value": 10,
             "minute": "2019-06-10 11:51",
             "action": "secondApp",
         },
         {
             "value": 100,
             "minute": "2019-06-10 11:51",
             "action": "thirdApp",
         },
         {
             "value": 10,
             "minute": "2019-06-10 11:52",
             "action": "firstApp",
         },
         {
             "value": 20,
             "minute": "2019-06-10 11:52",
             "action": "secondApp",
         },
         {
             "value": 115,
             "minute": "2019-06-10 11:52",
             "action": "thirdApp",
         }, ]
     }]
 }
```

Now consider that there are about 800 of these items in the data array. What I would like to do is to create a JSON object which has values for each and every timestmap, much like the following

```
[
   {
       "timestamp" : "2019-06-10 11:51",
       "firstApp" : {
           "value" : 1,
       }, 
       "secondApp": {
           "value":10,
       },
       "thirdApp": {
           "value" : 100,
       }
   },
   {
       "timestamp" : "2019-06-10 11:52",
       "firstApp" : {
           "value" : 10
       }, 
       "secondApp": {
           "value":20,
       },
       "thirdApp": {
           "value" : 115,
       }
   }
]
```

I have written the following code as such but its taking a lot of time (**about 10-12 seconds**) (which is quite expected) 
 Please refer to this CodeSandbox (https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-bartik-0r30j?autoresize=1&expanddevtools=1&fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js) link to see the code in action.

The problem that I am facing is that it takes a lot of time (and rightfully so) give  that

1. The dataset is huge
2. My code is bad - since there are too many loops here and there

I have no control over 1 but I have definitely control over 2 . Can you please give me some ideas as to how I can resolve this issue ?

**Update**
Here is a screenshot from the performance tab
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Thanks

```js
let data = {
  response: [
    {
      data: [
        {
          value: 1,
          minute: "2019-06-10 11:51",
          action: "firstApp"
        },
        {
          value: 10,
          minute: "2019-06-10 11:51",
          action: "secondApp"
        },
        {
          value: 100,
          minute: "2019-06-10 11:51",
          action: "thirdApp"
        },
        {
          value: 10,
          minute: "2019-06-10 11:52",
          action: "firstApp"
        },
        {
          value: 20,
          minute: "2019-06-10 11:52",
          action: "secondApp"
        },
        {
          value: 115,
          minute: "2019-06-10 11:52",
          action: "thirdApp"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

function massageData(data) {
  let historyData = [];
  let uniqueTimeStamps = [];
  let event = {
    timestamp: "",
    firstApp: {
      value: 0
    },
    secondApp: {
      value: 0
    },
    thirdApp: {
      value: 0
    }
  };

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let item = data[i];

    if (item.minute) {
      if (!uniqueTimeStamps.includes(item.minute)) {
        let timestamp = item.minute;
        console.log("--------------------");
        console.log(timestamp);
        event.timestamp = timestamp;
        event.firstApp.value = getDataValue(data, timestamp, "firstApp");
        event.secondApp.value = getDataValue(data, timestamp, "secondApp");
        event.thirdApp.value = getDataValue(data, timestamp, "thirdApp");
        console.log(event);
        historyData.push(event);
        uniqueTimeStamps.push(item.minute);
      }
    }
  }

  return historyData;
}

function getDataValue(data, timestamp, action) {
  for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
    let item = data[i];
    console.log(item);
    if (item["minute"] === timestamp && item["action"] === action) {
      return parseInt(item["value"]);
    }
  }
}

let workData = data.response[0].data;
let formattedData = massageData(workData);
console.log(formattedData);
```

Comment: This question might be more appropriate at [codereview.se]. Off topic at SO being too broad and primarily opinion-based (when someone asks "give me some ideas as how to")

Comment: please add the code to the question, because your link does not work.

Comment: Have a look at hashtables.

Comment: 800 items is not a large data set to process. Are you sure you're not prematurely optimizing here?

Comment: Define "a lot of time", is that seconds, minutes? How long do you expect it to take? The "much like the following" is not the same as your example output. It might be faster if *uniqueTimeStamps* is an object, where the timestamp is the property name and its value is its index in the *event* array.

Comment: @RobG I have updated , see the item in bold. I will also mention it here - it takes about 10-12 seconds

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I apologize but I don't clearly follow what you are trying to make me understand. Can you please clarify it a bit more ?  Thanks

Comment: @PatrickRoberts That JSON object is a small sample. Add a thousand more of them and you will see the difference. Also, my JSON is not as simple. I just gave a partial JSON . object here just to bring forth the problem that I am facing.

Comment: @Gagan I'm saying other than the claim that your code is taking 10-12 seconds to execute, there is no indication here that necessitates any further optimization. **Edit** thanks for the screenshot. I have removed my comment that is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a classic hash table for same timestamp and update the values with the hash table.

```js
function massageData(data) {
    var historyData = [],
        hash = Object.create(null),
        i, item;

    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        item = data[i];
        if (!hash[item.minute]) {
            historyData.push(hash[item.minute] = { timestamp: item.minute, firstApp: { value: 0 }, secondApp: { value: 0 }, thirdApp: { value: 0 } });
        }
        hash[item.minute][item.action].value = item.value;
    }
    return historyData;
}

var data = { response: [{ data: [{ value: 1, minute: "2019-06-10 11:51", action: "firstApp" }, { value: 10, minute: "2019-06-10 11:51", action: "secondApp" }, { value: 100, minute: "2019-06-10 11:51", action: "thirdApp" }, { value: 10, minute: "2019-06-10 11:52", action: "firstApp" }, { value: 20, minute: "2019-06-10 11:52", action: "secondApp" }, { value: 115, minute: "2019-06-10 11:52", action: "thirdApp" }] }] },
    workData = data.response[0].data,
    formattedData = massageData(workData);

console.log(formattedData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: so awesome of you to guide me. I will try to work on this code and will let you know. Please note that it might take me some time to confirm because this code is not that simple. I hope you will understand. Thanks once again.

Comment: One thing I didn't initially notice looking at your answer was that you removed the need to use `Object.values()` to create the array that gets returned, saving some time constructing the array from each of the property values in the hash table. Very nice. My answer ended up being more similar to yours than I intended because I didn't notice you had done the same thing until after I edited my answer.

Comment: @NinaScholz - Thank you sooo much. I was able to do as per your suggestion/code here and its so smooth now. You are a GodSend. Thanks once again. Your help is indeed much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Another similar approach involving the use of an object as a hash table is below. It should be a bit easier to follow:

```js
function massageData (data) {
  const events = [];
  const timestamps = {};

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const { action, minute, ...item } = data[i];

    if (!(minute in timestamps)) {
      const event = { timestamp: minute };

      events.push(event);
      timestamps[minute] = event;
    }

    timestamps[minute][action] = item;
  }

  return events;
}

const data = [{ value: 1, minute: "2019-06-10 11:51", action: "firstApp" }, { value: 10, minute: "2019-06-10 11:51", action: "secondApp" }, { value: 100, minute: "2019-06-10 11:51", action: "thirdApp" }, { value: 10, minute: "2019-06-10 11:52", action: "firstApp" }, { value: 20, minute: "2019-06-10 11:52", action: "secondApp" }, { value: 115, minute: "2019-06-10 11:52", action: "thirdApp" }];

console.log(massageData(data));
```

This will copy all properties in each item except for `minute` and `action` into an object in each `event` as the computed property `[action]`. If `value` is really the only other property that exists on each `item`, then the code can be simplified:

```js
function massageData (data) {
  const events = [];
  const timestamps = {};

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const { action, minute, value } = data[i];

    if (!(minute in timestamps)) {
      const event = { timestamp: minute };

      events.push(event);
      timestamps[minute] = event;
    }

    timestamps[minute][action] = { value };
  }

  return events;
}

const data = [{ value: 1, minute: "2019-06-10 11:51", action: "firstApp" }, { value: 10, minute: "2019-06-10 11:51", action: "secondApp" }, { value: 100, minute: "2019-06-10 11:51", action: "thirdApp" }, { value: 10, minute: "2019-06-10 11:52", action: "firstApp" }, { value: 20, minute: "2019-06-10 11:52", action: "secondApp" }, { value: 115, minute: "2019-06-10 11:52", action: "thirdApp" }];

console.log(massageData(data));
```

Comment: In your first example when you say ` const { action, minute, ...item } = data[i];` where is item coming from , please ?  Thanks for the answer though. Much appreciated, Sir

Comment: @Gagan that's called object rest syntax. It collects the properties of `data[i]` except for `action` and `minute` and initializes `item` as a new object containing them. It's part of the ECMAScript 2018 specification.